# How can I clear the theme mod settings?

Tags: php, functions, customization, theme-customizer

Ideally I am looking to add a button to the theme customizer that allows the theme to reset to default settings, although that may be asking for too much in one question so I am wonder if anyone knows how to clear the theme_mod settings so it reverts back to the stylesheet and not the overrides?

I created many custmization settings in my theme and after testing them my theme is looking a little funky and I figure it is pretty much mandatory that I have a button to reset the theme to default settings.

Does anyone have any experience they could share with me?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_theme_mods)?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that some themes (i.e. Twenty Eleven) use another row on the database called {$theme_name}_theme_options, so you'll need to delete that too.

Comment: You can look for the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183206/need-help-linking-a-button-to-a-function-in-wordpress-theme-customizer